# Understanding and applying k-means clustering for topic modeling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, topic-modeling, centroid

I have the following code that I found from https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/ on document clustering. While I understand the k-means algorithm as a whole, I have a little trouble wrapping my head about what the top terms per cluster represents and how that is computed? Is it the most frequent words that occur in the cluster? One blogpost I read said that the outputted words at the end represent the "top n words that are nearest to the cluster centroid" (but what does it mean for an actual word to be "closest" to the cluster centroid). I really want to understand the details and nuances of what is going on. Thank you!

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a restaurant.",
             "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
             "Google Translate app is incredible.",
             "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smiley face.",
             "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
             "Climbing ninja cat.",
             "Impressed with google map feedback.",
             "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

true_k = 2
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind]),
    print
```

Answer (score 2):

'Top' in this context is directly related to the way in which the text has been transformed into an array of numerical values. By using TFIDF you are, for each individual document, assigning each word a score based on how prevalent it is in that document, inverse to the prevalence across the entire set of documents. A word with a high score in a document indicates that it is more significant or more representative of that document than the other words.

Therefore with this generation of top terms for each cluster, they are the words that, on average, are most significant in the documents for that cluster.

The way it has been done here works and is efficient but I find it difficult to understand myself and I don't think it is particularly intuitive as it is difficult to comprehend why, if `cluster_centers_` are the co-ordinates for the centroids, then the features with the highest co-ordinate numbers are the top words. I kind of get it but not quite (if anyone wants to explain how this works that would be great!).

I use a different method to find the top terms for a cluster which I find more intuitive. I just tested the method you posted with my own on a corpus of 250 documents and the top words are exactly the same. The value of my method is that it works however you cluster the documents as long as you can provide a list of the cluster assignments (which any clustering algorithm should provide), meaning you're not reliant on the presence of a `cluster_centers_` attribute. It's also, I think, more intuitive.

```
import numpy as np

def term_scorer(doc_term_matrix, feature_name_list, labels=None, target=None, n_top_words=10):

    if target is not None:
        filter_bool = np.array(labels) == target
        doc_term_matrix = doc_term_matrix[filter_bool]
    term_scores = np.sum(doc_term_matrix,axis=0)
    top_term_indices = np.argsort(term_scores)[::-1]

    return [feature_name_list[term_idx] for term_idx in top_term_indices[:n_top_words]]

term_scorer(X, terms, labels=model.labels_, target=1, n_top_words=10)
```

The `model.labels_` attribute gives you a list of the cluster assignments for each document. In this example I want to find the top words for cluster 1 so I assign `target=1`, the function filters the `X` array keeping only rows assigned to cluster 1. It then sums all the scores across the documents row wise so it has one single row with a column for each word. It then uses `argsort` to sort that row by highest values to lowest, replaces the values with the original index positions of the words. Finally it uses a list comprehension to grab index numbers from the top score to `n_top_words` and then builds a list of words by looking up those indexes in `feature_name_list`.

Answer (score 0):

When words are converted into vectors, we talk about closeness of words as how similar they are. So for instance, you could use cosine similarity for determining how close two words are to each other. a vector of "dog" and "puppy" will be similar so you could say the two words are close to each other.
In other terms, closeness is also determined by the context words. So, word pair (the, cat) can be close, as per the sentences. That is how word2vec or similar algorithms work to create word vectors.

Comment: My question had to do more with what the centroid, specifically in document clustering, represents? If I am outputting top terms, what does "top" mean (most representative, most frequent)?